# Conversion failed when converting the varchar(max) value 'TNK_99' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working with MS SQL. I wrote a simple code which goes through columns in my table and find the columns with more than 30% zero value. I will save name of column with more than 30% zero in **@array**.**@count** just has number of columns and **@column** has name of all columns.

```
  DECLARE @array varchar(MAX)
  DECLARE @sql varchar(MAX),
  @column as varchar(MAX)
  SELECT @count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = 
  OBJECT_ID('UVE305_TREND_2.dbo.LOGTNK'))
  WHILE @counT>0
  BEGIN

      SET @column = (SELECT name FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('UVE305_TREND_2.dbo.LOGTNK') AND column_id = @count)
   SELECT @column

     SET @array = (SELECT COUNT(@column) FROM UVE305_TREND_2.dbo.LOGTNK WHERE 
     @column = 0 )
     select @array

     SET @count= @count- 1
END;
IF @r_count >= CAST(@array AS INT)
     SET @list= @column+','+@list;
```

when I tried to run my query I got following error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar(max) value 'TNK_99' to
>   data type int.

'TNK_99' is my column name.
any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This expression:

```
WHERE @column = 0
```

Is being converted to:

```
WHERE 'TNK_99' = 0
```

That is, it is comparing a *string* (which happens to be a column name) to a number.  By the rules of SQL the values are converted to numbers -- and you get a conversion error.

There is no simple way to solve this.  The solution involves dynamic SQL, which is rather more complex than your code.

EDIT:

The code looks like:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
WHILE @count > 0
BEGIN
    SET @column = (SELECT name FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('UVE305_TREND_2.dbo.LOGTNK') AND column_id = @count);

    SET @SQL = 'SELECT @array = COUNT(*) FROM UVE305_TREND_2.dbo.LOGTNK WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(@column) + ' = 0 )'

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@array int output', @array=@array output;

    SELECT @column, @array

    SET @count= @count- 1
END;
```

As with the original code, this assumes that all columns are numeric.  This code is a little vague on what "zero value" means.  Perhaps you intend:

```
    SET @SQL = 'SELECT @array = COUNT(*) FROM UVE305_TREND_2.dbo.LOGTNK WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(@column) + ' = ''0'' )'
```

Comment: You might want to check that the datatype of the column is numeric too, Gordon. Otherwise you'll likely to still get conversion errors. Otherwise you might end up with some dynamic SQL that has a `WHERE` clause like `WHERE [Name] = 0`, giving a nice error along the lines of `Conversion failed when converting the varchar(50) value 'Gordon Linoff' to data type int.` :)

Comment: Gordon Linoff ,your code returns NULL. it means it doesn't work properly